# Problem using intersection types with a trait

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, php-8.2

I am having a laravel model `Post` that extends `Model` and use a Trait of `Searchable`.

in `Searchable` trait I have a function:

```
namespace App\Models\Traits;
 
use App\Models\SearchEntry;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOne;
 
trait Searchable
{
    public static function bootSearchable()
    {
        static::created(function (Searchable & Model $searchable) {
            $data = $searchable->searchData();
 
            if (is_array($data)) {
                $data = implode('. ', $data);
            }
 
            $searchable->searchable()->create([
                'data' => $data
            ]);
        });
 
        static::updated(function (Searchable & Model $searchable) {
            $data = $searchable->searchData();
 
            if (is_array($data)) {
                $data = implode('. ', $data);
            }
 
            $searchable->searchable()->updateOrCreate([],[
                'data' => $data
            ]);
        });
 
        static::deleted(function (Searchable & Model $searchable) {
            $searchable->searchable()->delete();
        });
    }
 
    public function searchable(): MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne(SearchEntry::class, 'searchable');
    }
 
    abstract public function searchData(): string|array;
}
```

when i run this code i get this error:

```
 TypeError  App\Models\Post::App\Models\Traits\{closure}(): Argument #1 ($searchable) must be of type App\Models\Traits\Searchable&Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, App\Models\Post given
```

Comment: Full Searchable class please

Comment: But does your `Post` implements `Searchable` too? It's not enough to use trait

Comment: https://pastebin.com/T3t6FcHc this is the Searchable trait @WahyuKristianto

Comment: why not `(self $searchable) {}`?

Comment: As far as I know traits do not define types so you can't use them for type constraints

Comment: Searchable trait does not implement the Searchable interface. Better use `self`

Comment: Traits are a way to deal with limitations of single inheritance, but they are not part of the typing system as far as arguments, properties and return types are concerned. The preferred method to type against such a thing is usually an interface. Code can later reflect using [`class_uses`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-uses.php) if you really need to know if a specific trait is implemented, however I can safely say I’ve never had a need of that function in all of my years.

Comment: FYI, I've re-titled your question, because `A & B` denotes an "intersection type" (both A and B) rather than a "union type", which would be `A | B` (either A or B).

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) are often summarised as **compiler assisted copy-and-paste**. They are not part of the type system, only a compile-time aid for re-using a chunk of code. As such, you can't require that a particular argument "is" or "has" a trait, because once compiled, the trait is largely invisible.

[Abstract trait methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.abstract) can be used to require *internal* functionality, for the copy-and-pasted code to call directly with `$this` or `self`, but for an *external* requirement, you need to define an interface, and have the class declare that it implements that interface.

```
interface Searchable {
    public function searchable(): MorphOne;
 
    public function searchData(): string|array;
}

// ... 

class Something implements App\Models\Interfaces\Searchable {
     // paste definitions of bootSearchable() and searchable()
     use App\Models\Traits\Searchable;

     // define searchData() required by implementation in trait
     public function searchData(): string|array {
         // ...
     }
}
```